# Android UI - How to make View dividers overlapped by TextViews visible?

Tags: android, android-layout

The View dividers seem to be overlapped by TextView elements and made invisible in some cases on larger resolution screens.

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This is the fragment  to be displayed for a section associated with a tab -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_fragment3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2F3F4"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/acc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/account" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Paul Johnston"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/acc"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="#9e9e9e"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rentSpace"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Rent Your Space"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/rentspace"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="#9e9e9e"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accBooking"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="My Bookings"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/bookings"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="#9e9e9e"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/payDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Payment"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/payment"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="#9e9e9e"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accnt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Account"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/settings"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="#9e9e9e"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accAbout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="About"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/help"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#9e9e9e" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appLegal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Legal"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Version"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="v1.0"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

result:
[image: dividers gradually fade and disappear]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: how many pixels do you think `"0.1dp"` is on the different screen densities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you dividers are not overlapped by `textviews`. As you are using `Linearlayout` with `vertical` orientation.

Try this: increase the `height` of your divider:

```
  <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"  //change here
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#9e9e9e" />
```

your height `android:layout_height="0.1dp"` will not be visible in higher resolution devices as this devices has more pixel in per density.

Alternatively you can use different dimen value from dimens.xml based on different dpi level.

like:

```
dimens.xml (hdpi)
```

`dimens.xml (xhdpi)` etc..

Comment: top 3 dividers visually differ from bottom 3 dividers, do you know why?

Comment: i think it is something to do with your drawable image...cause the `<view>` code is same for all the dividers..